# How do you scrape a webpage to check if you need to solve for captcha

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, screen-scraping, watir-webdriver

I'm using 'watir', 'curb', 'nokogiri', 'esay_captcha_solver' and I'm trying to scrape the page so I'll know if a captcha has appeared and then solve it by getting the image url. However I'm not sure what to put in the if statement and how to scrape what I need.

```
    #=> SIGN IN
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
    browser.goto "https://soundcloud.com/login"
    browser.text_field(:id => "site-username").set "#{name}"
    browser.text_field(:id => "site-password").set "#{pass}"
    browser.button(:id => "log-in-submit-button").click
    if browser.body(:url => "https://soundcloud.com/login?captcha=true").text.include? (:id => "recaptcha_table")
        http = Curl.get("https://soundcloud.com/login?captcha=true") do |http|
        http.headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"
```

This if statement doesn't work because it doesn't seem to be able to read the text...in the browser it just stops when there's a captcha.

```
      end
      puts http.form_str
      easy_c = EasyCaptchaSolver.new(image_url: "...")
      easy_c.captcha
```

I want to be able to scrape the image url, I'm not sure how to get nogokiri to recognize the html code to scrape and then input the image url..

```
    else
      browser.goto "http://soundcloud.com/you/sets"
    end
```

The captcha html looks like:

[image: captch code]

Comment: Can you add HTML of the website that you want to scrape?

Comment: You want whole page of html? @AlexGolubenko

Comment: is that enough code or should i put more? @AlexGolubenko

Comment: So, you need get an url of this image? It's all what you need?

Comment: yeah I need it to scrape it and put in into the easy_captcha solver, but i also need ruby to read the page so that it knows ok its asking for captcha, because it doesn't always ask. @AlexGolubenko

Comment: Don't use a screen shot to display the HTML. Instead, copy and paste the HTML into your question where it's reusable. As is, you force anyone trying to help you to type in the HTML, which isn't likely to happen.

Comment: Okie doke that makes sense, thanks @theTinMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st line - checking captcha exists or aren't

2nd - get an url of captcha

```
if browser.element(:id => 'recaptcha_image').exists?
    img_url = browser.image(:id => 'recaptcha_challenge_image').src
    easy_c = EasyCaptchaSolver.new(image_url: "#{img_url}")
    easy_c.captcha
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it reads it, just too bad the easy_captcha_solver can't read captchas :\